# Vb.net Code syntax error

Tags: vb.net

I have following vb.net code and i am getting syntax error in it

**Update**

```
 Protected Sub OpenLogin_Click(ByVal src As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
        Dim StrUri As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
        Dim openid As New OpenIdRelyingParty()
        Dim b = New UriBuilder(Request.Url)
        With Key
            .Query = ""
        End With
        'var b = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Query = "" };

        Dim req = openid.CreateRequest(StrUri)

        Dim fetchRequest = New FetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First)
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last)

        req.AddExtension(fetchRequest)

        req.RedirectToProvider()

    End Sub
```

Now the error in code is "Key is Not declared" What should i do now for this

Comment: Remove the `Key` reserved word and the `End With`. Neither are required.

Comment: I have done this With {Query = ""  } But now error is "With Must end with a matching End Tag"

Comment: Then you need to not separate the with block onto a new line or use a line continuation character `_`.

Comment: I have done this Dim b = New UriBuilder(Request.Url) With { _
 Query = "" _
}   But now error is "End of Statement is Expected"

Comment: You didn't precede the Query with the accessor token `.Query`. Just see my answer below.

Comment: I haven't even the foggiest idea of what you're asking here. It doesn't help that the question has continually changed since the moment it was asked. Why don't you try learning the language first? A good book on VB.NET would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The `Key` reserved word is only to be used when identifying a multi-part key for grouping using `Enumerable.GroupBy`. It is not required for setting object properties inline with their constructor.
2. You are experiencing a problem whereby you have separated the `With` decorator onto a new line, which is syntactically incorrect because you are now treating it as a `With` block, which means that every dot access will target the variable immediately following the `With` statement. You need to use a line continuation character or put `With` on the same line as the object constructor:

**Ex 1**

```
Dim b = New UriBuilder(Request.Url) With {
            .Query = ""
        }
```

**Ex 2**

```
Dim b = New UriBuilder(Request.Url) _
            With { .Query = "" }
```

**EDIT:**

You cannot use this syntax with a Visual Studio 2005/.NET 2.0 project. Just construct the object then initialize the property:

```
Dim b As New UriBuilder(Request.Url)
b.Query = ""
```

Comment: I used ur both Ex1 and Ex2 but it is still giving error of "End of Statement is Expected". What do now ?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using and what .NET library?

Comment: I'm fairly certain inline property initialization is not supported that far back. Just construct your object and set the property on the next line.

Comment: Can u please translate my code for this because i am not exactly understanding the Syntax here

Comment: Sir With Your Answer My erro is Transfered to next line  fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)What should i do now sir

Comment: You should follow the advice of the parser and correct your syntax errors as it instructs you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you don't need the curly braces.

```
With Something
    .Property1 = True
    .Property2 = "Inactive"
    ' And so on 
End With
```

**UPDATE**

```
With Key 
  .Query = ""
End With
```

Why do you need a With clause here anyway ? The above is syntactically equivalent to

```
Key.Query = ""
```

Comment: What should i write for this With { Key .Query = ""  }
        End With

Comment: I'm with you on this one. Don't overcomplicate the syntax if it's not working. Just assign `Query` after dimensioning the object.

Comment: Sir Now the error is "key is not declared i am updateing my current code to question"

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Key variable or else remove it from your code.